# Oracle.DataAccess "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format" in MVC3 Web application

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-mvc-3, dll

I've got a ASP.Net 4 MVC3 web application that is trying to access an Oracle Database using the Oracle.DataAccess.dll, but is getting the error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its
>   dependencies.
>
> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

There are other variations.

I have tried different options on the dll properties and have also tried copying the various dependency dlls without any luck.

I have created a small test console application, using the same dll and dll property settings, and it is working. Why does a console app work but not a web app?

As mentioned I have tried copying the 'dependency' dlls to the bin folder, setting the dll properties, changing the platform target without any luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possibly trying to load a 32-bit assembly when running in 64-bit mode?  If you are running under IIS, you might need to set the `Enable 32-bit Applications` flag against the Application Pool to true, or target your project to x86 (instead of AnyCPU).

Comment: Check event viewer for more detailed description of issue.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to debug the web app using VS2010. I had to un-install Oracle in to debug another another application. Should I just put all the dll's in the bin folder?